# How to Add Partial Selected Treenode into SelectedNodes in p:tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I use tree component in PrimeFaces. In this component, selected nodes is added in selected nodes arrays automatically. However, I need to add partial selected nodes into this selected nodes array. What can I do in this situation, can you help me?

```
    <p:tree id="treCard" value="#{authorizeBean.rootCard}" var="Folder" propagateSelectionUp="false" showUnselectableCheckbox="true" style="border:0px none;background:none; " selectionMode="checkbox" dynamic="true" selection="#{authorizeBean.selectedNodes}">  

     <p:treeNode class="authorizationPage" expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed" >
            <h:outputText value="#{Folder.tag}">
             </h:outputText>
     </p:treeNode>
      <p:treeNode class="authorizationPage" type="page" icon="ui-icon-document">
            <h:outputText value="#{Folder.tag}" />
      </p:treeNode>

       <p:treeNode class="authorizationPage" type="tab" icon="fa fa-bars">
                 <h:outputText value="#{Folder.tag}" />
      </p:treeNode>

      <p:treeNode class="authorizationPage" type="button" icon="fa fa-square-o">
               <h:outputText value="#{authorizeBean.btnName(Folder.tag)}" />
      </p:treeNode>

     </p:tree>
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Finally I ended up iterating over the tree looking for partial selected nodes and adding them to an auxiliar array. Then merging this auxiliar array and the array used as backing bean by the tree for selected nodes in a new one. Finally assigning this new structure as the value for the variable holding the backing bean for selected nodes. This did the trick in my case. I guess there is no problem in performing if the tree is not too big.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a root node and attach the part that you want to show to your root example create root : `root= new DefaultTreeNode( new YourJavaClass(), null);`
after that you lined it with your partiel tree : `PartielTree = new DefaultTreeNode( new YourJavaClass(), root);`

Comment: It is needed that selected nodes and partial selected nodes are added in same array. However, now partial selected nodes are not added this array. @YagamiLight

Comment: I didn't understand your commente please provide more informations thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As primeface does not include partial selected node into selected nodes,
so below function is a hack to include partial selected nodes into the selected nodes and It must be called before using selectedNodes array everytime, else selectedNodes will not contain partially selected nodes. (calling everytime because primefaces updates this array on every request- pretty much ;) )
here 'selectedNodes' is a array of TreeNode where primeface framework will be storing selected nodes

```
public void updatePartialSelectedNodes() {

    Set<TreeNode> allSelected = new HashSet<>();

    if (selectedNodes != null && selectedNodes.length != 0) {
        for (TreeNode sel : selectedNodes)  {
            allSelected.add(sel);
            if (!((yourTreeDataObject)sel.getData()).isSupplier() && sel.getParent().isPartialSelected()) {
                allSelected.add(sel.getParent());
            }
        }
    }

    selectedNodes = new TreeNode[allSelected.size()]; 
    selectedNodes = allSelected.toArray(selectedNodes);
}
```

Edit1 : Other option and probably good one if the length of your tree in not greater than 100 nodes and not deeper than 2 level than You can iterate over the tree root node children and check using TreeNode.isSelected() or TreeNodes.isPartialSelected(), as the primefaces framework also update it in the main tree whether the node is selected or partial selected or not selected.

for a two level deep .. an example

```
for (TreeNode tn : this.treeRoot.getChildren()) { 
    for (TreeNode child : tn.getChildren()) { 
        if (child.isSelected()) { 
selectionString.append(((TreeNodeObjectDataWrapper)child.getData()).getId()); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```